# xml file from excel sheet data

Tags: python, xml, xls

Hello using the code snippet below, I created an xml below, but I notice that: the parameter order I use in the code is different from that in the output i.e. `<node y="-3749099.0" x="-45194.0" id="11542.0"/>` should be  `<node id="11542.0"  x="-45194.0" y="-3749099.0"/>` also the output is not as the desired output below. Can someone advise how I can:

- correct my code to get the correct output
- extend the code so that if I had to use an excel file with many columns (more than 3) I wont have to hard code `val[0], val[1], val[2]` as in `FIELD(id=str(val[0]), x=str(val[1]), y=str(val[2])),`

Code Snippet:

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.builder
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("emme_nodes1.xls")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
tags = [n.replace(" ", "").lower() for n in sh.row_values(0)]

for row in range(1, sh.nrows):
    val = sh.row_values(row)

    E = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()
    ROOT = E.network
    DOC = E.nodes
    FIELD = E.node
    my_doc = ROOT(
            DOC(
                FIELD(id=str(val[0]), x=str(val[1]), y=str(val[2])),
                )
            )
    print lxml.etree.tostring(my_doc, pretty_print=True)
```

Output:

```
<network>
  <nodes>
    <node y="-3748681.0" x="-45333.0" id="11543.0"/>
  </nodes>
</network>

<network>
  <nodes>
    <node y="-3747847.0" x="-44369.0" id="11540.0"/>
  </nodes>
</network>

<network>
  <nodes>
    <node y="-3748683.0" x="-45060.0" id="11541.0"/>
  </nodes>
</network>

<network>
  <nodes>
    <node y="-3750248.0" x="-45518.0" id="11546.0"/>
  </nodes>
</network>

<network>
  <nodes>
    <node y="-3750024.0" x="-45448.0" id="11547.0"/>
  </nodes>
</network>

<network>
  <nodes>
    <node y="-3749821.0" x="-44745.0" id="11544.0"/>
  </nodes>
</network>

<network>
  <nodes>
    <node y="-3750508.0" x="-45561.0" id="11545.0"/>
  </nodes>
</network>

<network>
  <nodes>
    <node y="-3750202.0" x="-45802.0" id="11548.0"/>
  </nodes>
</network>

<network>
  <nodes>
    <node y="-3749805.0" x="-45485.0" id="11549.0"/>
  </nodes>
</network>
```

Desired Output:

```
<network>
  <nodes>
    <node id="11542.0" x="-45194.0" y="-3749099.0"/>
    <node id="11543.0" x="-45333.0" y="-3748681.0"/>
    <node id="11540.0" x="-44369.0" y="-3747847.0"/>
    <node id="11541.0" x="-45060.0" y="-3748683.0"/>
    <node id="11546.0" x="-45518.0" y="-3750248.0"/>
    <node id="11547.0" x="-45448.0" y="-3750024.0"/>
    <node id="11544.0" x="-44745.0" y="-3749821.0"/>
    <node id="11545.0" x="-45561.0" y="-3750508.0"/>
    <node id="11549.0" x="-45485.0" y="-3749805.0"/>
    <node id="11548.0" x="-45802.0" y="-3750202.0"/>
    <node id="11549.0" x="-45485.0" y="-3749805.0"/>
  </nodes>
</network>
```

Excel sheet (emme_nodes1.xls):

```
 id         x           y
11542   -45194.0    -3749099.0
11543   -45333.0    -3748681.0
11540   -44369.0    -3747847.0
11541   -45060.0    -3748683.0
11546   -45518.0    -3750248.0
11547   -45448.0    -3750024.0
11544   -44745.0    -3749821.0
11545   -45561.0    -3750508.0
11548   -45802.0    -3750202.0
11549   -45485.0    -3749805.0
```

Comment: Attribute order in XML is completely irrelevant. If you build a system that relies on attribute order, you are making a mistake. Don't do that.

Comment: @Tomalak, does that apply even when the xml file will be used as input for a different application?

Comment: @Nobi Yes. If the other application reads XML correctly, then the attribute order does not matter.  (there are many very badly written applications that don't actually handle XML, just someone's incomplete understanding of some of it)

Comment: @dsh This applies *always*. Attribute order is declared irrelevant right in the spec. (I also have a hard time imagining a sane application that requires attributes to be in a certain order, because that would suggest and application that uses string functions for XML, and you must never use string functions for XML.)

Comment: @Tomalak Agreed. That's why I said "if ... correctly".  I have worked with brain-dead applications using their own home-grown parser that required elements each on their own line and similar atrocities. It is most definitely not sane, but I acknowledge it exists. I would even say that such applications invented their own format that simply resembles XML.

Comment: @dsh My mistake, I wanted to reply to the OP.  :)

Comment: I've had similar requirement, see if this can help you out https://github.com/newPrimitives/xls2xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally arrived at this solution, and it works perfectly

```
import xlrd
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element('network')
root.set('name', 'Network')
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
name = etree.Element('nodes')
root.append(name)   
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("emme_nodes1.xls")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for row in range(1, sh.nrows):
    val = sh.row_values(row)
    element = etree.SubElement(name, 'node')
    element.set('id', str(int(val[0])))
    element.set('x', str(val[1]))
    element.set('y', str(val[2]))
print etree.tostring(root,pretty_print=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Trace through the execution of your code.

What you have is this:

1. First row:

   1. Create a new XML document builder
   2. Create a new root element
   3. Create a new 'network' element
   4. Add it to the root node
   5. Print the entire document
2. Second row:

   1. Create a new XML document builder
   2. Create a new root element
   3. Create a new 'network' element
   4. Add it to the root node
   5. Print the entire document
3. Third row:
    repeat

---

What you want to do is this:

1. Create a new XML document builder
2. Create a new root element
3. First row:

   1. Create a new 'network' element
   2. Add it to the root node
4. Second row:

   1. Create a new 'network' element
   2. Add it to the root node
5. ...
6. Print the entire document

---

See if you can change your code accordingly and update this.